# Unit testing method for WebAPI2 Post method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2, http-post

I'm planning to create a unit testing project for my WebAPI controller post method.

My WebAPI controller is as follows,

```
[RoutePrefix("api/brands")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{brandID}/employee/{employeeID}")]
    public IHttpActionResult EnableParticipation(int brandID, int employeeID)
    {
        try
        {
            RequestService _requestService = new RequestService();
            bool result = _requestService.EnableParticipation(brandID, employeeID);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to write a Unit testing class for this HTTP Post method of my WebAPI controller.

What would be the best way to do this with mocking so that it does not hit the database.?

Here is what I have tried so far...

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void EnableParticipation()
    {
        var controller = new HomeController();
        //IHttpResponse response  = controller.EnableParticipation(1, 2);
        // How to mock the call
    }
}
```

Comment: Abstract `RequestService` out and have the abstraction explicitly injected into the controller. The actual implementation can be configured to be inject at run-time while a fake/mock can be injected when testing do that it does not hit the database

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you for your reply. Could you please provide me your solution code

Comment: Some helpful documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api